# Creating a non clustered index on a table with existing 1mln records affects that data immediately?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have a column with 1 mln records. If I create a non clustered index on Column 'A', and then perform filtering by that column, should I immediately feel that the request takes much less time? Or I should create the index on empty table first, and only then add data to table in order to feel the power of index?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague.  What DBMS are you using?  In MySQL and Postgres, you will find that your table gets locked while creating the index. In MS SQL Server (which I suspect you are using based on your verbiage), you can (in certain versions) specify "ONLINE ON" in your CREATE INDEX command which will build the index "in the background" and allow other transactions to continue.  The docs spell this out: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017.  Also, the usefulness of your index is entirely determined by what queries you run.

Comment: I'm using MsSql. The question is not about blocking other transactions while executing the Create Index command. The question is if I have data, will it be already copied to the index, so next query will query much faster ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot explain why you would or would not feel that a query is taking too much time.

But, once you have added an index -- and the statement completes -- then the index is available for any query that is compiled after that point in time.

As a rule, we can think that creating an index will remove the plan from the query cache.  This is effectively what happens, but the actual sequence of events is that the next execution of the query will replace the plan.  You can think of this as "delayed removal".

Creating an index on table when it is created means that the index will be available for all queries on the table.